# Merging two simple arrays into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to merge two arrays together, however I can't figure out how.

1st Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
```

2nd Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
        )
)
```

I know this is very simple to achieve, but my brain refuses to cooperate. Maybe I need more coffee...

// Thanks for all the downvotes :)

Comment: Drink a cup of coffie and think about `for` or `foreach` loop and fill the value in a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `foreach` to iterate:

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$b = array(1, 1);

$result = array();

foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    $tmp = array($value);
    if (isset($b[$key])) {
        $tmp[] = $b[$key];
    }
    $result[] = $tmp;
}

print_r($result);
```

And result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called "zipping" and can be done in php with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) when the first argument is `null`:

```
$x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$y = [1, 2];

$z = array_map(null, $x, $y);
print_r($z);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way, but it should work in this case:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array1 as $index => $row) {
    $newArray[$index] = array($row);
    if (isset($array2[$index])) {
        $newArray[$index][] = $array2[$index];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//1st Array:
$array_1 = array( 0=>'a',1=>'b',2=>'c');

//2nd Array:
$array_2 = array( 0=>1,1=>1);

//Result:
$holder = array();


for($i =0 ; $i <= max(count($array_1),count($array_2)); $i++){
    if(isset($array_1[$i])){
        $holder[$i][] = $array_1[$i];
    }

    if(isset($array_2[$i])){
        $holder[$i][] = $array_2[$i];
    }
}

//Required Result:
print_r($holder);
```

Hope this helps...;p